# Can files be restored from the Windows recycle bin from within Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, windows, files, filesystem

I am having some problems on my Windows machine partly due to my stupidity, but also due to uncooperative Microsoft software.

I recently discovered a hidden directory (`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`) when I noticed some weird executables running in Processes Explorer that I hadn't seen before and found out that this was were all the bloatware such as Zune Music, Bing News, Clip Champ, etc. was installed so without looking too closely, I took ownership of the directory and all sub directories and files and gave admin and users full privileges and started deleting everything.

Little did I know that was also where Paint, Notepad the MS Store and some Xbox apps were installed and because of the weird security and permissions Windows 10/11 has, while it allowed me to delete many (but not all) of those files, it won't just simply let me put them back.

They are sitting in the Recycle Bin, but I can't restore them. I can't move them. I can't copy them and Windows doesn't let you see or edit file permissions when they are in the recycle bin and even if I could, I would have to do that for many hundreds of files. I don't want to have to reinstall Windows just to restore Paint and Notepad. I can't use the MS Store because I deleted many of its files and I can't use Windows Update to help me because that was the first thing I purged when I installed Windows.

I know that the Windows recycle bin can be accessed from Ubuntu, but my questions are does Ubuntu show there original location and allow you to restore them to that location just like you can in Windows?

[image: Recycle Bin]

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Trash bin is just another directory in Ubuntu. It has no special functionality in Ubuntu at all.

Windows Trash and Linux Desktop Trash work differently and are not interoperable.

"*Does Ubuntu show their original location?*"

No.

"*Does Ubuntu allow you to restore them to that location*"

No.

Comment: Damn... I was hoping Ubuntu would save my ass on this.

Do you have any advice on how I can see the original location of the file from with in Ubuntu so I can manually move them?